# java regex char sequence

Tags: java, regex, sequence

I have a string with multiple "message" inside it. "message" starts with certain char sequence. I've tried:

```
String str = 'ab message1ab message2ab message3'
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile('(?<record>ab\\p{ASCII}+(?!ab))');
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    handleMessage(matcher.group('record'))
}
```

but `\p{ASCII}+` greedy eat everything.
Symbols `a`, `b` can be inside message only their sequence mean start of next message

Comment: You may try splitting string on each `"ab "` or whatever char sequence you have in front of it.

Comment: Try [`String[] res =str.split("(?!^)\\s*(?=ab)");`](https://ideone.com/67TF0N). If the `ab` is always at the end of the word, add `\\b` after `ab` in the pattern (=> `"(?!^)\\s*(?=ab\\b)"`).

Comment: How do you know if that charsequence is not part of the message ? Like _"I am absent"_ ?

Comment: replace `\p{ASCII}+` with `[^ ab]+`

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi bad idea: this would forbid any a or b in the message.

Comment: @MauricePerry you right.

Comment: Maybe [`String[] res =str.split("\\s*ab\\s+");`](https://ideone.com/JstcJX) is enough.

Answer (score 2):

`p{ASCII}+` is the *greedy* regex for one or more ASCII characters, meaning that it will use the longest possible match. But you can use the *reluctant* quantifier if you want the shortest possible match: `p{ASCII}+?`. In that case, you should use a *positive* lookahead assertion.

The regex could become:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<record>ab\\p{ASCII}+?)(?=(ab)|\\z)");
```

Please note the `(ab)|\z` to match the last message...

Comment: Thank you. Works perfect